# Запуск метода после загрузки компонента Vue

Tags: vue.js

Использую фреймворк Quasar 
Есть компонент для отображения статьи

```
<template>
</template>

<style>
</style>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Post',
  data () {
    return {
      data: {}
    }
  },
  methods: {
    get () {

    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Мне нужно сделать так, что бы метод get() вызывался автоматически при загрузки компонента. Как это сделать?

Comment: Вроде стандартный хук mounted работает и на quasar. Но не уверен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<template>
</template>

<style>
</style>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Post',
  data () {
    return {
      data: {}
    }
  },
  methods: {
    get () {

    }
  },
  mounted() {
     this.get();
  }
}
</script>
```

Попробуй вызвать метод в хуке mounted. Вот документация - https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted