# Запуск метода с переменной после/во время загрузки страницы

Tags: vue.js

с vue совсем недавно. 
Есть список, который состоит из какой-то информации и картинок. В текущей версии описанной ниже, картинки подгружаются после клика. Задача переделать отображение по клику на вывод картинок во время загрузки страницы.

```
<div class="example" v-for="element in list" :key="element.order">
  <div class="grid" @click="dropdownScene(element)">
    <div v-for="f in frame">
      <img :src="f.src" class="img-thumbnail"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
export default {
data(){
  return {
      frame: [],
      list: ...
  }
},
methods:{
    dropdownScene(scene) {
        this.frame = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < scene.data['thumbs'].length; i++) {
          if (this.frm[0].data[scene.data['thumbs'][i]]) {
            this.frame.push(this.frm[0].data[scene.data['thumbs'][i]]);
          }
        }
        return this.frame;
    }
 }
 </script>
```

В какую сторону копать или как решить задачу, насколько я понял хуки как [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/815557/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-vue) не помогут?

Comment: Привет. Я не понял, что Вам нужно переделать. Переформулируйте Ваш вопрос

Comment: Можно ли сделать так, чтобы метод dropdownScene вызвался сразу после загрузки страницы вместе с передачей параметра (element),  а не по клику

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы вызывать метод сразу после загрузки страницы, используйте хуки: `created` или `mounted`. Выглядеть это будет примерно так:

```
<div class="example" v-for="element in list" :key="element.order">
  <div class="grid">
    <div v-for="f in frame">
      <img :src="f.src" class="img-thumbnail"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
export default {
data(){
  return {
      frame: [],
      list: null,
  }
},
created: function() {
    this.dropdownScene();
},
methods:{
    dropdownScene(scene) {
        this.frame = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < scene.data['thumbs'].length; i++) {
          if (this.frm[0].data[scene.data['thumbs'][i]]) {
            this.frame.push(this.frm[0].data[scene.data['thumbs'][i]]);
          }
        }
        return this.frame;
    }
 }
 </script>
```

---

Инициализируйте `list`. После этого, за счёт того, что vuejs реактивный фреймворк, он увидит, что `list` был изменён и перерендерит его. Но здесь нужно быть внимательным. Если Вы будете менять лист вне `created`, тогда это нужно делать с помощью `$set`:

```
<div class="example" v-for="element in list" :key="element.order">
  <div class="grid">
    <div v-for="f in frame">
      <img :src="f.src" class="img-thumbnail"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
export default {
data(){
  return {
      frame: [],
      list: null,
  }
},
created: function() {
    this.list = [];  // Откуда здесь должны взяться значения?
    for (let i = 0; i < this.list.length; i++)  {
        this.dropdownScene(this.list[i])
    }
},
methods:{
    dropdownScene(scene) {
        this.frame = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < scene.data['thumbs'].length; i++) {
          if (this.frm[0].data[scene.data['thumbs'][i]]) {
            this.frame.push(this.frm[0].data[scene.data['thumbs'][i]]);
          }
        }
        return this.frame;
    }
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: К сожалению, вы повторяете ответ, который я указал по ссылке. Он не подходит для случая, когда нужно передать аргументы в this.dropdownScene(). Первый for раскладывает list, результат этого for нужно передать в dropdownScene. В случае с created или mounted, насколько я понял, передавать аргументы нельзя

Comment: @Sh1ft поправил

Comment: List инициализирован это статический json данных.  Который представляется list: jsonData.map(...) . В этом и вопрос,  можно ли так передать данные, чтобы метод с данными не по клику вызывался, а по загрузке страницы

Comment: @Sh1ft Инициализируйте данные в `created`, как я показал выше. Чем это не подходит?

Comment: Я, возможно, что-то не понимаю, но где в вашем коде вызывается метод dropdownScene ?

Comment: @Sh1ft примените к каждому элементу листа в `created` `dropdownScene`. См. ответ